# How can I add the displayName to the Firebase user? (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I can save the email and the password with Firebase Authentication. I also save this information with Cloud Firestore. But how can I add and save the **displayName** after registering?

my code:

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
try {
  AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser user = result.user;

  // create a new document for the user with the uid
  await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
      .updateUserData('User', user.email, 'test.de/test.png', user.uid);
  return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
```

}

the register form button:

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() => loading = true);
    dynamic result = await _auth
        .registerWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password);
    if (result == null) {
      setState(() {
        error = 'Valid email, please';
        loading = false;
      });
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`updateProfile` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html) given in the FirebaseUser class to update the name and photo url.

```
updateProfile({String displayName, String photoURL}).
```

For email you can use the different method
`updateEmail(String newEmail)` which is a async method.

Or to save the username directly into the firestore, after successful login you can use 'set' method of the FirebaseFirestore to save email, password and the username.

Comment: As of October 2021, `updateProfile()` is deprecated and `updateDisplayName()` could be used for this.

Answer (score 10):

Here's the code if you want to save the Username together with the email and password

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; 

//register with email & password & save username instantly
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String name, String password, String email) async {
  try {
    UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    User user = result.user;
    user.updateProfile(displayName: name); //added this line
    return _user(user);
  } catch(e) {
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `updateDisplayName()` instead of `updateProfile ()`, Its deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **`updateDisplayName()`** and **`updatePhotoURL()`** methods on a `User` object to add the displayName/profile image to Firebase user.

```dart
final userCredential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: email,
  password: password,
);

//After creating a user in Firebase, we then are able to change name/pictue
await userCredential.user?.updateDisplayName(name);

await userCredential.user?.updatePhotoURL(imageUrl);
```

As of october 2021, **`updateProfile()`** is **deprecated**, and you should use **`updateDisplayName()`** and **`updatePhotoURL()`** instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
late User userFirebase;
Future<UserCredential> userCredential =await //Your code signin or signup
await userCredential.then((UserCredential value)  {
userFirebase = value.user!;
});
await userFirebase.updateDisplayName(event.name);
```

Comment: Please add some details explaining your code

Comment: this doc can help you
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/overview