# How can I add a photoUrl to the current user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

In my app I choose an image with the image picker dart package ([pub.dev link](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)). Then I upload this image to Cloud Storage. I also can get the url from the database, but how can I add this url to the current user as photoUrl? How can I update the firebase user?

image picker code:

```
  getImage(BuildContext context) async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      cropImage(image);
      _showDialog(context);
    }
    setState(() {
      _image = image;
      print("Image Path $_image");
    });
  }
```

upload code:

```
  uploadPic(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_image.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("profilbilder/" + fileName);
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_image);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;

    // Photo URL
    var dowurl = await (await uploadTask.onComplete).ref.getDownloadURL();
    String url = dowurl;
    setState(() {
      print("Profile Picture uploaded");
    });
  }
```

Comment: That should be done with the same `updateProfile ` method as was used in your previous question to update a user's display name. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63869474/how-can-i-add-the-displayname-to-the-firebase-user-flutter-dart

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FirebaseUser object to store a user's profile photo's url.

Refer here: [Manage users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

And [Firebase getUrl](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser#public-abstract-uri-getphotourl)